# How to let logged-in user connect to database securly? JWT?

Tags: firebase, api, security, mobile, jwt

I am making a mobile app with my custom API on AWS, firebase auth and firestore. I want to make secured connection:
- prevent MITM attack between client and AWS, and between client and firebase store
- prevent anybody to make request (and accept request only from mobile app)

```
Firestore
  |(<- should be secure)
User  -  Firebase Auth
  |(<- should be secure)
AWS EC2
```

Should I use JWT? Does anybody know how to use it on firebase auth?

Answer (score 0):

I have used JWTs previously to allow a user’s login state persist on different sub domains on the same root domain (as Firebase does not do this natively). Check out this article:

https://dev.to/johncarroll/how-to-share-firebase-authentication-across-subdomains-1ka8

It may help with auth and JWT! It will allow you to authenticate in both backend and frontend.